# Different results from [ForeignKey] attribute vs. OnModelCreating or EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

For background: I'm trying to keep my EF POCOs free from references to EF, so all model configuration code is going into either OnModelCreating or EntityTypeConfiguration classes instead of using attributes (thus avoiding the reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema).  The problem is when the foreign key is not established by the attribute it seems to be ignored when the model is built.  Here's an example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Which generates this:

```
create table [dbo].[Groups] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    primary key ([Id])
);
create table [dbo].[People] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    [GroupId] [int] null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
alter table [dbo].[People] add constraint [Person_Group] foreign key ([GroupId]) references [dbo].[Groups]([Id]);
```

Perfect.

But move that to OnModelCreating (or equivalent EntityTypeConfiguration code) with something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.Group)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.GroupId);
```

And the result is this (for either a new or migrated DB):

```
create table [dbo].[Groups] (***same as above***);
create table [dbo].[People] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    [GroupId] [int] null,
    [Group_Id] [int] null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
alter table [dbo].[People] add constraint [Group_People] foreign key ([Group_Id]) references [dbo].[Groups]([Id]);
alter table [dbo].[People] add constraint [Person_Group] foreign key ([GroupId]) references [dbo].[Groups]([Id]);
```

Why is Group_Id being created and why isn't GroupId being used instead?

Thanks!

Comment: I should point out that I know not using an attribute or the fluent API in this case would work because EF is smart enough to pickup GroupId as the FK.  But that's not really the point.  First, because that wouldn't be true if it were GroupFK instead of GroupId (at least without adjusting conventions).  And second, and really more importantly, I'd like to understand why it's making this distinction in this case especially because it is smart enough to figure it out in all other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your mapping is wrong.

Since you have a navigation property in `Group` you need to include it in the mapping like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.Group)
    .WithMany(t => t.People) // <---
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.GroupId);
```

Otherwise EF will use the navigation property for a different relationship between the 2 entities and create another foreign key.

Comment: Looks like I may have marked that too quickly.  Yes, that does work in OnModelCreating but I just put it into an EntityTypeConfiguration<Person> class and it fails.  Same issue as above, adds Patient_Id.

Comment: @Ryan - Sounds highly unlikely - are you sure the EntityTypeConfiguration is hooked up in the OnModelCreating method?